# Make menu inside frame popup over parent frame

Tags: html, css, asp.net, menu, frames

I have a menu inside a 20px height frame.

This menu's height is highter than 20px, of course.

When I hover the menu, I can see it only inside the frame, so it's impossible to navigate trough it.

[image]

How can I make this menu appear outside the frame's limits? I want it to show up on the entire page.

I don't think there is a need to add code to this question, since it's nothing specific.

Comment: If it's inside a frame element, this won't be possible. The frame is a window into another page, and the contents of that page are restricted to the frame container. You have to increase the size of the frame, reduce the size of the elements inside the frame, or get rid of the frame and include the menu code in the code of your index page.

Comment: Do you know how I can add a page's content to a parent page without using frames?

Comment: You can take the HTML elements from the child page and insert those elements into the HTML of the parent. If you want to reuse HTML code in multiple different pages without copying and pasting, you'll probably need to use a server-side scripting technology such as PHP or ASP to generate your HTML. Alternatively, I think you could use Javascript to request the child HTML document from the server and insert the HTML into the DOM of the parent.

Comment: I'm using masterpages now and I had a different problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37140788/iframe-with-aspx-page-makes-page-stop-rendering