# iframe with aspx page makes page stop rendering

Tags: asp.net, forms, iframe

I have an iFrame inside my index page. This iFrame contains an aspx page with a form inside it, with `runat=server`.

For some weird reason, anything I add after the iFrame is not being rendered to the page.

I tried adding text, a div, nothing is being added after when I run the page.

Code:

```
<body>

        <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" Height="80px">
        <iframe name="LogoFrame" id="LogoFrame" src="asp/Logo.aspx" 
            scrolling="no" 
            style="border-style: hidden; padding: 0px; margin: 00px; width: 100%; height: 100%" 
            width="100%"/>
        </asp:Panel>

        <form id="MainMenu" method="post" runat="server">

        <asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server" Height="38px">

            <table class="tableMenu" id="MainTable" style="BACKGROUND-COLOR: #e2eded" cellSpacing="0"
                cellPadding="0" width="100%" border="0">
                <tr class="trMenu2" vAlign="middle">

        // Some other things below, including the closing of Panel2 and MainMenu form
```

When I run and inspect the page...

[image]

If I remove the iFrame, the rest of the page renders properly.
What is up with that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect it's because the iframe tag is self-closing and iframes should not be self-closing. If you replace ' `/>`' with '`></iframe>`', I think that should resolve the problem.

Comment: Yeah I had done it before. I forgot to answer my own question, but since you did it already, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the iframe is out of the `form` tag. But you put the iframe inside a Panel, which is an asp.net tool. You can try Removing the panel, or moving the code inside the form tags.